# How can I do a nested lightcone integral?

Tags: special-relativity, integration

I want to do an integral of the form $I(x-y)=\int d^{D+1}z_1...d^{D+1}z_n f(x-z_1)...f(z_n-y)$ where $x,z_1,...z_n,y$ are all (D+1) vectors and $f$ depends only on the proper times between them.
$z_i$s lie in the causal interval between $x$ and $y$ ($x$ is in the causal future of $y$) and each $z_i$ is nested in the lightcone of of its predecessor i.e. $z_n$ is in the lightcone of $z_{n-1}$ which is in the lightcone of $Z_{n-2}$ and so on up to $z_1$.
Also note that I want to do this in Minkowski spacetime and the usual form of $f(\tau)$ is an exponential. Any ideas will be welcome.